# Difference between NSMutableData's mutableBytes and bytes methods

Tags: objective-c, byte, nsmutabledata

Both return the same pointer. I know `- bytes` belongs to `NSData`, why does `NSMutableData` introduce `- mutableBytes`? Is it just for code clarity so it is more obvious you are accessing mutable data? Does it really matter which one is used?

```
NSMutableData* mydata = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[mydata appendData: [@"hello" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"%p", [mydata mutableBytes]);
NSLog(@"%p", [mydata bytes]);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why `NSMutableData` might provide a separate `mutableBytes` method:

- As you suggested in your question, using `mutableBytes` makes it clear to the reader that you want to change the data.
- The `bytes` method returns a `const void *`.  The `mutableBytes` method returns a `void *`.  If you want to change the bytes, you need a `void *` with no `const` qualifier.  The `mutableBytes` method eliminates the need to cast away the `const` qualifier.

In theory there could be a third reason: the `-[NSData mutableCopy]` method could return an `NSMutableData` that points to the same buffer as the original `NSData`, and only create a new, mutable copy of the buffer when you call `mutableBytes`.  However, I don't think it's implemented this way based on my very limited testing.

Comment: Just to add slightly to @rob's answer, the `- bytes` method is readonly, **even when called from NSMutableData**.  Is is part of the base class, however if you are using NSMutableData and want a mutable copy of the bytes, you call the `- mutableBytes` function so that you can make changes to it (which is what mutable means).

Comment: Anyone know the internals of NSMutableData data management? Does the `- mutableBytes` pointer have all the data exactly in one row, or does it segment the data in chunks of for example 1kb and at the end of each segment is a pointer to the next 1kb segment? (I hope that made sense).

Comment: @Dabbu `NSData` and `NSMutableData` store their contents as one contiguous array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

One addition to the [rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9747041/3345644) and his comment:

> @Dabbu NSData and NSMutableData store their contents as one contiguous
>   array of bytes.

The thing to keep in mind here is that this behavior was changed in iOS7: now `NSData`/`NSMutableData` are not guaranteed to keep contents as one contiguous array. It could be stored as multiple chunks.

So when you call `bytes`/`mutableBytes`, they will copy and flatten contents into one contiguous array of bytes, if needed, and then return a pointer to this contiguous chunk.

Depending of what you're trying to do, it may cause an unexpected performance penalty or excessive memory consumption for large buffers.